# PHP don't get select info with $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, excel

I'm working on a webpage that generate an excel file, that I want to select the language I want between English and French. So, in that page, I have two `select` inputs, one of those it's the language selector.
The other one it's on the trainer.

I call them in php :

```
$formateur=$_POST['nomFormateur'];
$query1="select * from formateur where formateurId=$formateur";
$info=info_query($query1);
$nomFormateur=$info['formateur'];

$lang=$_POST['lang'];

$date1=$_POST['date_debut'];
$date2=$_POST['date_fin'];
```

When I select all what I want like : 
[My option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFayY.png)

PHP, didn't take value of my second `select` (the language one) :

```
<td>
    <select name="nomFormateur" id="nomFormateur" class="name">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php   
        $query="select * from formateur";
        $rows=get_array($query);

        foreach($rows as $value) {
            echo '<option value='.$value['formateurId'].'>'.$value['formateur'].'</option>';    
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td align="left"><font size="2" color="gray">Langue :</font></td>
<td>
    <select name="lang" id="lang" onChange="name_click()">
        <option value="0">-----</option>
        <option value="1">Anglais</option>
        <option value="2">Francais</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

When my Excel file open, I saw the good trainer, the good date, but the language it's still on English, that i choose, nothing, English or french. But I want that if I choose english (value 1), they show in english, but if I choose French (value 2), it's in french, not english.

It's the only think that's not working. I do two different call in mysql to bring the excel in english or in french, in regard of this `<select>`

I try with Javascript and it's show me the good answer that I passed in an input and in an alert when I tested, but still not able to get the information in php

Javascript function :

```
function name_click(){
    var value_select = document.getElementById("lang").value;
    document.getElementById("my_var").value=value_select;
}
```

Can someone can help me?

Comment: seems like I am not getting through here. Ok well you have answers below, you ask them because I won't post an answer to "get" an answer. and I have deleted a relevant comment to the reason why your code failed.

Comment: Hi Fred -ii-. I tried like this, for my query, ad it's work!! Where the problem? I know it's not this because i already not it's was not a problem to call different, but i will try

Comment: *"I tried like this, for my query, ad it's work!! Where the problem?"* - so what's the problem then if you say it works?

Comment: The first select it's ok, it's not that want I need help, it's for the second one, with the language selection that PHP didn't take care, that's my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you're help! I was looking for an answer while i'm waiting and find something. It was that my option was not an array

```
                            <select name="lang" id="lang">
                            <option value="">-----</option>
                                <?php   
                                    $array = array("Anglais", "Francais");
                                    $lengh=count($array);

                                    for($x=0;$x<$lengh;$x++){
                                        echo '<option value='.$x.'>'.$array[$x].'</option>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                        </select>
```

Now, the php take the value of $lang and the excel take the language i want

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it's because you forgot to close the first select tag? I'm pretty sure it's related to this ;)

Comment: I close it, but still don't select which one I want

Answer (score 0):

This javascript function is unnecessary because the select automatically will get the value. May this is where the issue is.

Comment: I clean the javascript function without anything! Still don't work :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a select nested within a select?

Comment: I looking for that and close all my select that was open!!